# Laravel, Follow-Unfollow System Issue

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm developing an api for a social media like. This app has a follow-unfollow system. I did my follower list and follower list query and response . But, I wanna add follow info(boolean) in response. How to solve clear this problem? (Sorry for my bad English)

I want this response:

```
"data": [
    {
        "user_id": 3,
        "username": "example",
        "name": "Example",
        "photo": "default.jpg",
        "is_following": true
    }
]
```

Current response:

```
"data": [
    {
        "user_id": 3,
        "username": "example",
        "name": "Example",
        "photo": "default.jpg",
    }
]
```

---

User model in follow relationship:

```
function follows(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(self::class,"follows","followed_id","following_id")->select("users.id","username","name","photo");
}

function followers(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(self::class,"follows","following_id","followed_id")->select("users.id","username","name","photo");
}
```

My Resource:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        "user_id" => $this->id,
        "username" => $this->username,
        "name" => $this->name,
        "photo" => $this->photo(),
        "is_following" =>
    ];
}
```

Comment: What does the `is_following` actually mean? Does it mean that the listed use is following the authenticated user? And what is your controller code? You could solve this in the resource, by adding extra data to the array. Currently nothing is added...

Answer (score 0):

In your User model define an accessor that return true/false with your "following" logic.

```
public function getIsFollowingAttribute()
{
    if (condition)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

After this add this to User model to include it in array and JSON representations

```
protected $appends = ['is_following'];
```

[Read this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)

Comment: I know appends but, my json response is list (or array or collection). My json response will be a list and each item will "is following" property for list. Doing database query every time is wrong (n + 1 problem). How should I establish a database relationship?

Answer (score 0):

I asked this kind of question the other day and I was trying to do it with two tables, but a friend said that I could solve it with one table. If you wish, you can look at the location and look at the problem and its solution.

[Laravel API JSON customization and table relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65327577/laravel-api-json-customization-and-table-relationship)

Comment: I browsed your post. But, your json not exists "is_following". I want similar this [link](https://prnt.sc/w6jefk). How can ı do this?